# HTML CanvasRenderingContext2D - how to draw line to current mouse position, removing old lines, preserve photo

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I need to annotate an image with an arrow.

The following code adds photo then draws line over on mouseDown, mouseMove, mouseUp but the result is many lines. If there is a notion of layers, I don't know the verbage.

I have tried `CanvasRenderingContext2D.restore()` and `CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect`.  `clearRect()` also removes the photo from the context.

[This is a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/URWru/)  of exact behavior I need in JS and without `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.  I have been unsuccessful in incorporating what it does starting with its `new fabric.Canvas..`

html:

```
<canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

typescript:

```
  @ViewChild('canvas')
  public canvas: ElementRef;

  private canvasNE: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private imageStor = new Image();

  ... 

  private async configCanvas() {
    this.canvasNE = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = this.canvasNE.getContext('2d');

    this.cx.lineWidth = 3;
    this.cx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.cx.strokeStyle = '#000';

    this.imageStor.onload = () => {
      this.canvasNE.width = this.imageStor.width;
      this.canvasNE.height = this.imageStor.height;
      this.cx.drawImage(this.imageStor, 0, 0, this.imageStor.width, this.imageStor.height);
      this.cx.save(); 
      // ^This like likely isn't doing anything needed.
    };

    const mouseDown$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.canvasNE, 'mousedown');
    const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.canvasNE, 'mousemove');
    const mouseUp$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.canvasNE, 'mouseup');

    mouseDown$.subscribe(down => {
      mouseMove$
        .takeUntil(mouseUp$)
        .subscribe((move: MouseEvent) => {              
          // this.cx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasNE.width, this.canvasNE.height); 
          // ^This removes the original Image
          // this.cx.restore();
          // ^This was a stab in the dark.  
          this.cx.beginPath();
          this.cx.moveTo(down.offsetX, down.offsetY);
          this.cx.lineTo(move.offsetX, move.offsetY);
          this.cx.stroke();
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: The next function will fire for every 'mousemove' event, so a new line will be drawn for every 'mousemove' event until the next 'mouseup' even. So there will be multiple lines. To "animate" the line moving as you move the mouse you do need to `clearRect()` of the last frame before draring the next line/frame, but you are right this will remove anything else drawn, including the photo. You can't just delete a line once drawn to the canvas it is flat (no layers if you will). You could put the image behind the canvas or redraw the image every frame.

Comment: I think I will go with 2 canvases overlapping, 1 for image and 1 for annotation.  Then combine when done to accomplish layering and avoid redrawing image every mouseMove.  Thx for help co-worker :)

Comment: Don't be afraid of drawing on canvas multiple times. In any canvas game or graphics you see on the web the canvas is totally repainted 25+ times/s with way more complex objects.